# Use laws of the algebra of sets to show that $X' \cap Y' = (Y \cup X)'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Use laws of the algebra of sets to show that:

> $X' \cap Y' = (Y \cup X)'$

Can I get some help on how to solve this? I have tried so far to use De Morgans Laws to make it go from:

> $X' \cap Y'$

to

> $(X \cup Y)'$

but how do I switch the letters of x and y around?
so it's like this?

> $(Y \cup X)'$

I thought at first, to use the commutative laws but that will simply change the union to an intersection which I don't want.

If I have formatted my question wrong, please tell me so I can know in the future.

Comment: (X∪Y)′ is identical to (Y∪X)′

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commutativity of sets under set union gives us $$(Y\cup X)' = (X\cup Y)'$$

Furthermore, it is also true that sets commute under set intersection: $A\cap B = B\cap A$.

Comment: Ah, I made a simple mistake regarding commutative laws, thank you.

Comment: You're Welcome!